# zsh: how to make tab completion need no space to next word after cursor?

Tags: bash, autocomplete, zsh, tab-completion

There is an annoying difference between `zsh` and `bash` tab completion:

Imagine you write some command and want to add something at the beginning of the line:

```
$ compute --some --stuff
```

then you jump to the beginning of the line and line and start to write `sudo` (bad example - just to demonstrate)

```
$ sudcompute --some --stuff
    ^ <---cursor
```

`bash` would let you complete `sud` to `sudo` while `zsh` would try to complete  `sudcompute`.

So in this case you would have to write a space, jump back one character and try to tab-complete.

In case you're still used to `bash` you would try to tab-complete after `sud` and render the command you started to write into something utterly useless.

So for short: is there an option to let `zsh` complete the phrase to the left of the cursor regardless whether or not it's terminated by a space?

Comment: I usually realize I need sudo after running a command, and therefore `sudo !!` will do the trick

Comment: [up] for it doesn't answer my question but it's helpful in such a case indeed

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just looked around in my `.zshrc` file and I think this is what you want:

```
bindkey '^i' expand-or-complete-prefix
```

Where `^i` is `<Ctrl-I>` which is usually tab.

Comment: This at least does what I want to, thanks! I will have a deeper look into the differences of `expand-or-complete` and `expand-or-complete-prefix`, but I think you found the answer.

Comment: @frans AFAIK the only difference is that `expand-or-complete` will use word under cursor while `expand-or-complete-prefix` will use word left of cursor.